# Returning void function

Tags: c++, return, void

Im pretty new here. Hopefully, I will be able to contribute over time. Im having a trouble to have this new values assigned. Whenever I run the code, they get only zeros.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void CoordTransform(int xVal,int yVal,int xValNew, int yValNew)    {


   xValNew = (xVal + 1) * 2;
   yValNew = (yVal + 1) * 2;

 return void();
}


int main() {
   int xValNew = 0;
   int yValNew = 0;

   CoordTransform(3, 4, xValNew, yValNew);
   cout << "(3, 4) becomes " << "(" << xValNew << ", " << yValNew << ")" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Google `C++ passing by reference.` It's one of the first lessons.

Comment: You have to pass the values as pointers. xValNew and yValNew in your CoordTransform are variables that are known only within the scope of that function. See if this link helps: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_pointers_to_functions.htm

Comment: `return void();` is unnecessary. For a `void` function, just `return;` with no argument, or you can omit the `return;` and fall off the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing arguments as you have is passing "by value".  Changing the value in the function has no affect on the original variable holding the value that was passed to the function.

Pass by reference instead.  The reference is to the original variable, so changing the parameter in the function changes the original variable.

```
void CoordTransform(int xVal, int yVal, int& xValNew, int& yValNew) {
   xValNew = (xVal + 1) * 2;
   yValNew = (yVal + 1) * 2;
}
```

Additionally, a void return value means you don't return anything directly from the function.  Don't use a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is the following

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void CoordTransform( int xVal, int yVal, int &xValNew, int &yValNew )    
{
    xValNew = (xVal + 1) * 2;
    yValNew = (yVal + 1) * 2;
}

int main() 
{
    int xValNew;
    int yValNew;

    CoordTransform( 3, 4, xValNew, yValNew );
    cout << "(3, 4) becomes " << "(" << xValNew << ", " << yValNew << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The third and the forth parameters of the function must be reference types.